# Нужно переключить слайды при нажатии на кнопку "Next"

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно переключить класс active между блоками с одинаковым классом?
Чтобы скрывался текущий слайд и показывался след. слайд и в обратную сторону при нажатии на "Prev"

```css
.step {
    display: none;
}

.step_active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="steps">
                    <div class="step active"></div>
                    <div class="step"></div>

                <div class="btn_nav">
                    <button type="button" id="prev_button" class="control control_hide control_prev">Prev</button>
                    <button type="button" id="next_button" class="control control_next">Next</button>
                </div>
```

Comment: в чем у вас сложность в решении?

Comment: У меня есть валидация полей. И если поля заполнены мне нужно, чтобы слайд перелистывался. У двух слайдов одинаковый класс. Может Вы знаете как можно через проверку на this, чтобы оно скрывало текущий слайд и открывало другой? Или может какой-то другой способ, кроме как указать через :first-child

Answer (score 0):

Введи **data-id** с номерами (индексами) и при переключении сделай активным **id + 1**